# The geometric intuition of these sets

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to understand this sets, for example, went they say "gluing the north pole to the south pole" do they mean "switching the north pole to the south pole?"

And by a "torus of revolution" mean that is not a solid torus?

I'm quite loss with the geometric intuition, and the homotopy type, but I need to understand first the sets to define the functions. Thank for any help!

[image]

Comment: $S^1$ is constructed from $[0,1]$ by _gluing_ $x=0$ with $x=1$

Comment: They are defining a quotient space.

Comment: Also, that was the last listenable DRI record.

Comment: A torus of revolution seems to be the surface of a ring torus, i.e. a conventional torus with a gap in the centre.  Otherwise you would not be able to fit the disk into that gap

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally get what they were talking about!